# Objective-C: instance pointer with protocol

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers, protocols, cocoa-design-patterns

Normally when developer makes a pointer to the instance of class which implements a protocol, she does this:

```
id<ProtocolName> myInstance = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

Is it OK to be more specific about the instance's class type and use it like this?

```
SomeClass<ProtocolName> *myInstance = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

Or in method:

```
- (SomeClass<ProtocolName> *)someMethodWithArg:(int)arg;
```

With implementation (assume SomeSuperClass is superclass of SomeClass):

```
- (SomeClass<ProtocolName> *)someMethodWithArg:(int)arg
{
   SomeClass<ProtocolName> *instance = [[SomeSuperClass alloc] init];

   return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is OK. (Although I think your last example uses `SomeClass` where it should be using `SomeSuperClass`, but I understand what you meant.)

In fact, sometimes you will need to do that. For example, to use `autorelease` or `release` on an `NSObject` (which is not available to an `id<ProtocolName>` (unless `ProtocolName` explicitly conforms to the `NSObject` protocol)), you would have to use:

```
NSObject<ProtocolName> *protoObj = [....];
[....]
[protoObj autorelease];
```

Comment: You can use `id<ProtocolName>` if your protocol conforms to the `NSObject` protocol.

Comment: `id`, by itself, would match any method anywhere.  `id<Protocol>` explicitly limits the namespace to just `Protocol`, which is why you need `SomeClass<Protocol>*` or `id<Protocol,NSObject>` or declare your protocol to also implement `NSObject`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments -- those add more explicit details/limitations to my example. Maybe I should have just left it at "Yes it is OK" :-)